# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Mi Yodeya's [second moderator election](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 1 new moderator is:

[image: Isaac Moses]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes! (Or at least, learns any *new* ropes we might have added recently.)

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6512018232180736/0).

Comment: Welcome back Isaac!

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Scimonster for being willing to serve.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone is wondering, this is the election output (assuming I'm reading the file properly). For more information about the method used see [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/166155)

```
Loading ballots from file judaism-stackexchange-com-2017-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 3 candidates and 105 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 105 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Mi Yodeya Moderator Election 2017 using Meek STV.
3 candidates running for 1 seat.

 R|Isaac Moses    |Daniel         |Scimonster     |Exhausted      |Surplus        |Threshold      
==================================================================================================
 1|      79.000000|      14.000000|      12.000000|       0.000000|      26.499999|      52.500001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Isaac Moses has reached the threshold and is elected.

Winner is Isaac Moses.
```